# Overload operator< for std::pair

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to overload the operator< for std::pair class.

```
template <>
bool operator< (const std::pair<int, std::string>& lhs, const std::pair<int, std::string>& rhs) {
    return lhs.first > rhs.first || (!(rhs.first > lhs.first) && lhs.second < rhs.second); 
};
```

I get the following error: **no function template matches function template specialization 'operator<'**

I also tried:

```
template <>
bool std::pair<int, std::string>::operator< (const std::pair<int, std::string>& lhs, const std::pair<int, std::string>& rhs) {
    return lhs.first<rhs.first || (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second); 
};
```

This time I get the error: **overloaded 'operator<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)**

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Without the `template <>` your 1st version should be OK.

Comment: The first one should work but you don't need to make it a template - try leaving off the `template <>` at the beginning

Comment: A different reason could be (with the [`template <>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) specialization), that you forgot to compile your code with the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, I am compiling with the `-std=c++11` flag. The problem was with that template. It's ok now. Thank you. ^^

Comment: `-std=c++` != `-std=c++11` but you're right, what I referred to is all c++14.

Comment: The logic behind your overrides is invalid, because it does not establish ordering. Try comparing `x={2,"A"}` and `y={1, "B"}`. The results of both `x<y` and `y<x` will be `true`, which means that the overload cannot be used for ordering.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're right. It was supposed to be `return (lhs.first > rhs.first || (rhs.first == lhs.first && lhs.second < rhs.second);`.

Comment: Even if the specialization compiled, you should still prefer overloading with a nontemplate function: gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you write is a template specialisation, which assumes that you have previously defined the template.

Like mentioned in the comments, in this case you don't need to make the operator overloading a template, since you have already specialised the `pair`.