# how to overload std::vector<int> operator<?And be used for std::sort?

Tags: c++11, stl

```
namespace std {
  bool operator<(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2)
  {
      if (v1[0] < v2[0] && v1[1] < v2[1])
          return false;
      else
          return true;
  }

}

int main() {
vector<vector<int>> a1{ {1,2},{3,4} };
sort(a1.begin(), a1.end());
for (auto num : a1)
    cout << num[0] << num[1] << endl;
return 0;
```

}

why when I remove the namespace std, and it doesn't work anymore?It's about scope of sort?And why it does not need template specialisation?(just like here said [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720794/overload-operator-for-stdpair))

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` comes in two flavors. The first uses `operator<` to compare elements. The second takes a custom comparison predicate.

You probably want to use the second one here.

```
bool compare(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2) noexcept
{
    if (v1[0] < v2[0] && v1[1] < v2[1])
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

std::sort (a1.begin(), a1.end(), compare);
```

As for why your original code works only if you wrap it in `namespace std`, you need to read up on [Argument Dependent Lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (I'm new to stackoverflow, and I just know how to check my message recently)I think the reason why my original code work because I create a new function operator<(. It has nothing to do with the vector template. When sort use operator<(), it may obey the argument dependent lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I have get the answer, the up one is not correct. The key of this question is sort only know functions in the std, just like this:

```
namespace mySpace {
void func()
{
    cout << "my space" << endl;
}
void func2()
{
    func();
}
}
using namespace mySpace;
void func() {
    cout << "other " << endl;
 }

int main() {
    func2();
    return 0;
 }
```